# Is it better to use div- or button-elements [iPhone][in android]?

Tags: iphone, html, android, css

I'm developing a site for the iPhone. Later for android.
Now I have some links in that site. 
To see that it is a link I'd like to style the div-element like a button so that one can see that it is a link and clickable.

Is it better to use div- or button-elements here?
Are there any information about which way is a better way?

In android I had the problem that clickable div-elements were not as sensitive as the button-elements. 
Do you have an idea why?

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT: I decided to use div-elements though I already worked with buttons. You can find [the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216051/hovered-button-element-loses-style-after-changing-background-color)here.

Comment: I don't know anything about Android or iPhone development, but I would always opt for button elements as it was developed exactly to be a styleable clickable button, and trying to make a div clickable can be a real pain.

Comment: Well, I'd like to accept your answer. Would you mind posting it again as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use button elements only......