# hovered button-element loses style after changing background-color

Tags: css, button

This is a CSS-Question.
In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cNY5v/1/) you can see a button.
It has got two span-elements inside. One with `float:left;` the other with `float:right;`.

The style is a normal button-style.
When clicking that button on the iPhone or hover it in a Browser the style gets lost.
This is because I changed the background-color.

Is there a way to change the background-color without losing the whole button-style?

EDIT:
Here are the two images: The first button is a normal button-element. The second button is a button where I changed the background-color ... this is what it looks like when I'm hovering over a button.
[image: Normal Button] [image: hovered button]

Comment: What exactly is your question? "The style gets lost" is pretty vague and doesn't really describe what's  happening here.. What is your desired effect?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "style gets lost"? What happens?

Comment: Works find in IE8. What browser are you using? You may need to post before-and-after images.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well, tested it in several Browsers. Thanks for testing @ egrunin

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. It looks like the rounded corner is gone when hovering, while a border is added. I'm afraid there's not a easy way to get what exactly you want as the behavior & appearance of Button is controled by system. Maybe you can try to replace it with a div

Comment: @tshao - that wasn't the answer I was hoping for :-) Anyway, post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it ;-)

Comment: ok, hopefully i can eventually have a solution for you, maybe several hours later. :)

Comment: I alreday have the divs, so no worries ... would've been great if it worked with the button-element. Let me know if you find sth.

Comment: @Faili: The js Fiddle doesn't have any of that styling, it's just a normal button. Are you sure that's what you meant to show?

Comment: The text is not the same, the background-color is red ... that's the only difference. I told you that it is a normal button-element. My problem was when hovering the button and setting the background-color to blue the rounded corners are gone and a border is added. You can see what I mean when comparing screen one and two ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean. It looks like the rounded corner is gone when hovering, while a border is added. I'm afraid there's not a easy way to get what exactly you want, as the behavior & appearance of Button is controled by system.

Maybe you can try to replace it with a div, which you have full control of the style (chaning the style via JS when hovering).

Answer (score 0):

All's working fine for me. However floating-right elements should always be placed before floating-left elements. Don't know if it will change anything.